# How to import svg into a dwg using Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-designautomation

have implemented a viewer using Autodesk Platform Services on .NET Core. In the bucket I upload 2D drawings in .dwg format.

I enabled the markup feature in the viewer, so now I can make any markup on top of the .dwg

What I have for the moment looks like this:
[image]

I need to save this dwg with the markups I did, and either have it as a 2nd dwg inside the bucket or to override the original one.

I have checked the following link on importing svg into dwg but so far I can't find something for my case.

[Autodesk Design Automation API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/autocad/)

In case someone knows maybe another way on handling this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way you can import SVF markups into AutoCAD modelspace using Design Automation.

You have to build the workflow, I will attempt to give you a rough idea, [I have plan to put together small POC] but do note importing SVF markups into AutoCAD is a complex task, mainly AutoCAD is unitless, you need to consider scaling, rotation, the transformation matrix that we get from `NOP_VIEWER.model.getPageToModelTransform()` may not be accurate if the base drawing don't have any units.

AutoCAD have this feature in ACC docs [https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-64CFD65E-ABD0-49A8-9218-D4E2D22BC070]

The SVG returned by markupExt.generateData spans the entire “paper space” with origin being in the center.
You need to extact markup element, and construct equivalent AutoCAD entity.

For example for a Polyline Markup.

The SVG metadata could

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" layer-order-id="markups-svg" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; transform:scale(1,-1); -ms-transform:scale(1,-1); -webkit-transform:scale(1,-1); -moz-transform:scale(1,-1); -o-transform:scale(1,-1); transformOrigin:0, 0; -ms-transformOrigin:0, 0; -webkit-transformOrigin:0, 0; -moz-transformOrigin:0, 0; -o-transformOrigin:0, 0; " width="2512" height="1278" viewBox="-2.8503522409754964 -0.0033170086124281184 16.707355499267578 8.500000000008502" pointer-events="painted" cursor="crosshair">
  <metadata>
    <markup_document xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-model-version="4"/>
  </metadata>
  <g cursor="inherit" pointer-events="stroke">
    <metadata>
      <markup_element xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" stroke-width="0.006651017214405641" stroke-color="#ff0000" stroke-opacity="1" fill-color="#ff0000" fill-opacity="0" type="polyline" position="5.100938961004755 5.52700380516462" size="6.537950022205427 3.824334898282383" rotation="0" locations="-2.5107590370117476 1.912167449141192 3.2689750111027136 0.6484741784044061 3.1692097513539013 -1.912167449141191 -3.2689750111027136 -1.7591940532098942"/>
    </metadata>
    <path id="markup" d="M -2.5107590370117476 1.912167449141192 l 5.779734048114461 -1.2636932707367858 l -0.09976525974881234 -2.560641627545597 l -6.438184762456615 0.15297339593129688 z" stroke-width="0.006651017214405641" stroke="rgba(255,0,0,1)" fill="none" transform="translate( 5.100938961004755 , 5.52700380516462 ) rotate( 0 )"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can see, markup position and polyline location.

Check which viewport, markups are, use that viewportid.

```
const xform = viewer.model.getPageToModelTransform(VIEWPORT_ID);
viewer.model.getData().paperHeight, viewer.model.getData().paperWidth
Now transform point from Viewer coordinate system to AutoCAD WCS.
const point = new THREE.Vector2(/* read from the markups */);

transformCoordinates = (coordinate, pageToModelTransform) => {
    const data = viewer.model.getData();
    const PAPER_WIDTH = data.paperWidth;
    const PAPER_HEIGHT =data.paperHeight;

    coordinate.x = coordinate.x + 0.5 * PAPER_WIDTH;
    coordinate.y = coordinate.y + 0.5 * PAPER_HEIGHT;

    return new THREE.Vector3(coordinate.x, coordinate.y, 0).applyMatrix4(pageToModelTransform);
};
```

Exports markups as JSON from viewer to your server.

Something like this.

```
 [HttpPost("markups")]
 public IActionResult Markups(Markup[][] markup)
 {
     _markups = markup;
     JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer
     {
         Formatting = Formatting.Indented
     };
     serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
     
     serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"..\markups.json"))
     {
         
         using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
         {
             var mainArray = new JArray();
             foreach (Markup[] sub in markup)
             {
                 var subArray = new JArray();
                 foreach (Markup m in sub)
                 {
                     var jobject = JObject.FromObject(m);                           
                     subArray.Add(jobject);                            
                 }
                 mainArray.Add(subArray);
             }
             serializer.Serialize(writer, mainArray);
         }
     }
     
     return Ok();
 }
```

Now in AutoCAD.

Create a Pline.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_markup.Locations.Length; i++)
    

    acPoly.AddVertexAt(i, new Point2d(m_markup.Locations[i].XCoord,  m_markup.Locations[i].YCoord), 0, m_markup.Size, m_markup.Size);
}
```

Small demo:
https://clipchamp.com/watch/hlkHPqahUyd